# Jquery: How can i display alert when i click a pagination button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8

[image]

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-end px-4 pt-4" id="myListItemPagination" >
{{ $listItems->links() }}
</div>
```

I want to ask how can I display an alert message when I click a pagination link?

because I'm trying to make pagination using ajax.

```
<script>
    $("#myListItemPagination pagination page-item")on('click','a' ,function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('tst');
    })
</script>
```

this is the script that I have. please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by selecting the class `page-item` selector

```
$(function(){

    $('.page-item').on('click', function(){
  
    alert('test');
  
  });

})
```